# How to insert a date and then add a hour, minute and second to the date inserted in a oracle database from a stored procedure executed from java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a class in `Java` with an attribute of the type `java.sql.Timestamp` and I want to insert the value of that attribute to a column of the type `Date` in a a oracle database table using a `storedprocedure` i already can do this but when I want to try to add an hour or a minute or a day to the value of that Date column it says `invalid number`

Here is my class with the

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Person {
   private Timestamp birthday;

   public Timestamp getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Timestamp birthday) {
        this.birthday= birthday;
    }
}
```

Here is my table in the oracle database

```
create table person (
id_person number(3) not null,
DATE  birthday NOT NULL
);
```

And here is the part where i set the timestamp in my store procedure

```
callableStatement.setTimestamp(1, person.getBirthday());
```

And here is the store procedure where i'm trying to add and hour to the `date` birthday column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_hours
    (
       p_birth          IN person.birthday%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
insert into person
    (
        id_person,
        birthday
    )
    values 
    (
        SEQ_Person.nextval, 
        p_birth + 1/24
    );
```

What i want to know if there's a way to insert a date with hh:mm:ss using a storedprocedure without the miliseconds from the timestamp, and if there's no way to this how can i add a hour a minute or a day to my already inserted timestamp date column

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INTERVAL` keyword for converting literals to time units:

```
insert into person
(
    id_person,
    birthday
)
values 
(
    SEQ_Person.nextval, 
    p_birth + interval '1' hour
);
```

Also, you can use the [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function for converting a `TIMESTAMP` into a `DATE` (stripping off milliseconds), e.g. like this:

```
select to_date(to_char(systimestamp, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
    'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I added an example with `to_char` and explicit date formats.

Comment: My previous comment might have come across harsher than I meant it to *8-) You can also just do `cast(some_timestamp as date)`.